# Unable to post ng-model data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-model

I have an angular app that consists of a three tabbed form. Each tab is using its own controller and designated service.

When the submit button is pressed on the form, the function found in MainCtrl entitled `$scope.post`is suppose to post all form field data that was retrieved from each form fields ng-model.

On the server side, I receive the posted object that is formed in the Main Controller. This POST contains all the values for each object property except for work. I receive an empty object as a value for the work property.

Why am I unable to retrieve the work.comments ng-model found in the code for my template? Even when console loggin, I am unable to retrieve this item.

This is my first go at an Angular app and I am really trying to learn how to do things properly. If you happen to notice something inherently stupid, please do let me know.

Controller:

```
.controller('WorkCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, TaskService, WorkService) {
    $scope.work = {};
    WorkService.add($scope.work);
});
```

Service:

```
.factory('WorkService', function() {
    var work = {};
    return {
        add: function(data) {
            work['work'] = data;
            //work = data;
        },

        list: function() {
            return work;
        }
    };
})
```

Template:

```
    <div class="list" ng-controller="WorkCtrl">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
          <button class="button button-clear item-icon-right" ng-click="newTask()">New Task<i class="icon ion-ios-plus-outline"></i></button>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
          <span class="input-label">Comments</span>
          <textarea placeholder="Comments" rows="6" ng-model="work.comments"></textarea>
        </label>{{work | json}}
      </div>
 <div ng-controller="TaskCtrl"> 
    <div ng-show="ifTasks()">
      <div class="row header">
          <div class="col tableRow">Task</div>
          <div class="col tableRow">Edit</div>
          <div class="col tableRow">Remove</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="task in tasks track by task.id">
        <div class="col tableRow">{{task.choice}}</div>
        <div class="col tableRow" ng-controller="WorkCtrl"><button class="button button-small button-balanced" ng-click="editTask({{task.id}})">Edit</button></div>
        <div class="col tableRow"><button class="button button-small button-assertive" ng-click="del({{task.id}})">Delete</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Main Controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, SiteService, TaskService, WorkService, LabourService) {
    $scope.toFetch = [];

    var obj = {
        site: SiteService.list(),
        tasks: TaskService.list(),
        work: WorkService.list(),
        labour: LabourService.list()
    };

    $scope.post = function() {
        console.log(obj);
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:1818/send/report',
            method: 'POST',
            data: obj,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: in your controller, WorkService.add($scope.work);  doesn't seem to be called by anything. you could try add a watcher to detect changes in your ng-model and then call the add function

Comment: Its strange because every other controller is using this exact same pattern. I read about watchers and try adding one. Hopefully that will help. Is this considered a standard procedure when retrieving ng-model values via services?